# Show touch point with S-Pen as well (instead of just finger)

Tags: s-pen, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

Samsung's android shows a cursor while using the S-Pen but hides it when you actually start touching.

In the Developer Options there are 2 relevant options, one shows a nice white circle where you touch, but does not react to the pen, and the "cursor Position" setting does react to the pen, but is in my opinion a bit too much on the screen, especially with the path and all.

So is there some way to get a simple touch indicator that also works with the pen, e.g. for screen recordings?

I am using a Galaxy Tab S6 Lite with Android 13.

Comment: There is a small circle on my phone

Comment: the small circle generally only appears only when the screen is using capacitive touch (like using fingers or a capacitive stylus, usually recignizable by a wide round rubber tip like 5mm in diameter), but when you use an inductive stylus like the s-pen the circle will not show

Answer (score 0):

The [Samsung support page](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00077673/) mentions behavior close to what you're describing:

> Maybe you’d like to see a pointer displayed on the screen to show the path of your S Pen.

But neglects to describe the setting that would enable this. They do say, however, that it should be found at `Settings > Advanced Features > S Pen`.

The [Verizon support page](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-218908/) seems to call it `Show pointer`. Additionally [this video](https://youtu.be/syIpKA3YZaU?t=119) shows an S Pen causing different display responses when screen recording that are available via the screen recording settings through the Samsung floating Screen Recording menu (shown in the video) and further customizable from `Settings > Advanced Features > Screenshots and screen recordings`.

Comment: the pointer is the one I mentioned in the original post, it s only shown while in "air view" which means the stylus is floating just enough above the screen to still be recognized but the tip isnt pressed in by e.g. touching the screen. as soon as you touch down, the pointer goes away.

on the screenshot from the samsung page also shows it under air view.

the integrated screen recorder looks neat (the effect is hilariously huge, maybe it can be tweaked, must have been a comparatively recent addition, I dont remember it being there when I got the tablet a few years ago

Comment: Let us know if you find it in the settings of your Tab S6 lite!